# How to make angular 4 live reload to point to the correct address?

Tags: angular, sockjs, nanoboxio

I have an angular 4 application which is set up in Nanobox.

On the local machine it runs on `localhost:4200` on the Nanobox I run it on `http://172.21.0.5:4200/` as per Nanobox suggestion.

When the application load in `http://172.21.0.5:4200/` I get this error:
`zone.js:2933 GET http://localhost:4200/sockjs-node/info?t=1508200471270 net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`

This error doesn't happen in Localhost, and because of that error my live reload is not working.

Thanks in advance.

**Edit**

It is dev environment. I need somehow tell angular file watcher to communicate with `http://0.0.0.0:4200` or `http://172.21.0.5:4200`

I don't know where is the angular live reload script. I can't find anything online either. 
I thought it is `Webpack`, but I can't find anything about it.

Comment: Live reload is a development time feature, it's not something that you use in production to update your application

Comment: I am not using it in the Production. Nanobox is my development environment.

Comment: Then why? localhost will be faster.

Comment: Using Nanobox or Docker will isolate the local environment. Also you can simply push that into production, and manager your server with no issues.
In the production I will `ng build` it.

Answer (score 0):

As per understanding you wanted to run angular application on client machine, to do so follow 3 simple steps

1) enable prod mode-

```
import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';

// Enable production mode unless running locally
if (!/localhost/.test(document.location.host)) {
  enableProdMode();
}
```

2) build application in prod mode- base will be set in index.html to navigate all CSS and js files
ng build prod --base="/folderName/"

3) deploy dist folder and explore.

Comment: I don't need Prod Mode as it is a dev server. Nanobox is like Docker. I need to somehow tell my live reload to communicate with `http://0.0.0.0:4200`

Answer (score 0):

After lots of digging, there is no straight answer for this.

Here is my solution with Nanobox:

Grab the IP Address that Nanobox suggests:

[image]

Then use `ng serve -host 172.21.0.5` this should bypass the issue of livereload.

Also in your `boxfile.yml` make sure you use `fs_watch: true`.

Nanobox is looking at `0.0.0.0` so you need to make sure in your 
`angular-cli.json` in the default section add:

```
"defaults": {
    "styleExt": "scss",
    "component": {},
    "serve": {
      "port": 4200,
      "host": "0.0.0.0"
    }
  }
```

This should do it.